# Worklight - features of worklight not available in BB and windows?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Can you please help me on what all worklight features are not available on blackberry and Windows? Is there any place where it is documented, if not can you please help me out on this?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is a public feature parity document, however the following are Worklight features that are currently not supported in BlackBerry 6/7,7.1/10 and Windows Phone 7,7.5,8:

Perhaps you are looking for something specific?

- Direct Update (all)
- nativePage (all)
- Cordova plug-ins (all)
- Skins (Windows Phone 7,7.5,8)
- JSONStore (all)
- Custom Device Provisioning (all)
- Push Notifications (all)
- SMS Notifications (all)
- Dojo (all)
- Shell/Inner app (all)
- Container for Advanced Pages (module 45) (all)
- Application Center (all)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately i did not get what does it mean, you mean to say the mentioned features are not available for the BB and wiindows? what do you mean by (all)?

Comment: Yes, the features mentioned in my list are currently not supported in BlackBerry and Windows Phone. You asked about BlackBerry and Windows Phone. "all" means "BlackBerry and Windows Phone".

Comment: Thanks Idan for the reply, Can you please bit elaborate the features of What do you mean by "natiavePage", "Cordova plugins", "Dojo", "Container for Advanced Pages"

Comment: Taken from here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started/

If your question was answered, please mark it as such. Thanks.

Comment: thats what i am wondering, i did work on cordiva lugin concept in blackberry, but its a pure phonegap application for "Barcode reading", is it different from what you have mentioned here?

Comment: Yes. In a Worklight application you would use a Cordova plug-in to access some device hardware/software features. I advise reading the Worklight Getting Started training modules; these modules explain what that you ask (it is getting a bit out of scope for your original question).

Comment: Thanks Idan for your immediate responces, Iam sorry to take one step back on this, you said earlier, Cordova Plugin wont work in windows and blackberry, can we remove this feature from the above list?

Comment: What do you mean?? You asked for features that are currently not supported by Worklight applications for the BlackBerry and Windows Phone platforms. Cordova Plug-ins are not supported.