# IBM Worklight - Limitations in BlackBerry and Window Phone

Tags: blackberry, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

Is this an official news from IBM?

"I do not believe there is a public feature parity document, however the following are Worklight features that are currently not supported in BlackBerry 6/7,7.1/10 and Windows Phone 7,7.5,8:

Perhaps you are looking for something specific?

```
Direct Update (all)
nativePage (all)
Cordova plug-ins (all)
Skins (Windows Phone 7,7.5,8)
JSONStore (all)
Custom Device Provisioning (all)
Push Notifications (all)
SMS Notifications (all)
Dojo (all)
Shell/Inner app (all)
Container for Advanced Pages (module 45) (all)
Application Center (all)
```

"
[Worklight - features of worklight not available in BB and windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840022/worklight-features-of-worklight-not-available-in-bb-and-windows)

If not, where can I find the document of "Limitation of Worklight on BlackBerry and Window Phone"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a document does not yet exist still.

The changes to the list above in Worklight 6.0.0.x are:

- Application Center is now supported in BlackBerry 6/7
- Push Notifications are now supported in Windows Phone 8
- SMS Notifications are now supported in Windows Phone 8 and BlackBerry 6/7/10
- Native Page support in Windows Phone 8 (missing documentation, though)

In addition, in the upcoming Worklight 6.1.0 there are some more changes:

- App Center supported on Windows Phone 8
- Dojo now supports BlackBerry 6,7,10 and Windows Phone 8

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Anyway, I think that such document as well as the road map of the product should be in public.

Comment: Finaly, I found it here [Mobile OS Feature Mapping for Worklight V6.0](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039422)